# How to find size of a column on MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

I have created a table named test. In the table, I'm having id(int), name(varchar(10)), created date(datetime) and updated date(datetime). There I need to find the size of the name column.

**select length(name) from test**. The query resulted the length of the column but I need size of the column. Could anyone plz suggest me to achive this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html

Comment: What do you call the *size* of a column? Please illustrate your question with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
 foo VARCHAR(10) 
);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'test'
  AND column_name = 'foo'; -- Your column name
```

**Output**

```
| CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH |
| ------------------------ |
| 10                       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eESq7KRXNJPRvxFJUw8tPT/1)